# Помогите с решением проблемы

Tags: linux, windows

[image: При запуске windows 10]

[image: Выскакивает вот это]

Хотел установить Kali Linux рядом с Windows 10. Сделал образ на флэшке, а потом решил зайти в саму флэшку и... случайно нажал не туда и запустил exe файл. Потом вроде бы ноут перезагрузился(точно не помню) и мне после перезагрузки предлагали выбрать операционную систему. Выбираю вторую и в итоге выводится диспетчер загрузки. По сути ничего сделать с этим не могу. Как это дело убрать? А то уж слишком бросается в глаза. И, возможно ли то, что из-за этого я не могу установить какой-либо дистрибутив Linux? А то устанавливал(пробовал) ubuntu, kali, mint - бесполезно. То зависает загрузка, то интерфейс не выводится. Заранее благодарю за решение моих проблем

Comment: Пробовали это? https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub

Answer (score 0):

Я так и не понял что ты нажал, но видимо винду ты потерял или испортил.
Втыкай флешку линукса грузись с нее (через boot usb-bios)без установки и записывай новый образ винды для её восстановления. Надеюсь ты вкурсе чтобы установить линукс с виндой нужно зарание на винде отрезать диск и сделать этот кусочек полностью не ипользуемым [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я знаю, что нужно выделять память для линукса. Винду я не потерял, т.к. запускать ее спокойно могу. А вот что насчет испортил, то это возможно. Вообще, когда я пытался установить линукс, то при вводе логина и пароля пропадал интерфейс(это кали), на убунте просто фон без интерфейса был, а на минте грузилось-грузилось, да зависло